# segue to viewController UILabel not showing text

Tags: objective-c

I have a segue from a tableViewController to a viewController with a UILabel to show text (notes), however, the text is not appearing.

For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 wine *barbera =[[wine alloc] init];
[barbera setName:@"Barbera"];
[barbera setNotes:@"stuff about this..."];
[list addObject:barbera];

wine *chardonnay=[[wine alloc]init];
[chardonnay setName:@"Chardonnay"];
[chardonnay setNotes:@"stuff about this..."];
[list addObject:chardonnay];

wine *cheninBlanc =[[wine alloc]init];
[cheninBlanc setName:@"Chenin Blanc"];
[cheninBlanc setNotes:@"stuff about this... "];
[list addObject:cheninBlanc];
```

My Segue:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
DescriptionWineViewController * dwvc= [segue destinationViewController];
[dwvc setCurrentWine :[self currentWine]];
}
```

I also attempted:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
DescriptionWineViewController * dwvc= [segue destinationViewController];
[dwvc setNotes :[self notes]];
}
```

And the viewController it is to segue to:

```
@interface DescriptionWineViewController ()

@end

@implementation DescriptionWineViewController

@synthesize descriptionLabel;
@synthesize currentWine;
@synthesize notes;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
[super viewDidLoad];

[descriptionLabel setText: [currentWine notes]];

 }
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: `[dwvc setCurrentWine :[self currentWine]]` Great, but please add some logging: `NSLog(@"%@", [self currentWine]);` I am betting it is nil.

Comment: you are correct Matt.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with `currentWine`. You need to implement this in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to set it to the selected item.